# Upload image sequentially to a REST API via retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, rx-java

I am looking for an implementation strategy to upload multiple image to a server sequentially. I am using API's from http://uploads.im to upload my images. It **does not allow** choosing multiple images in one multi part POST request. Hence I have to upload image sequentially.

I have an interface as shown below. 
 [image]

User would "click" multiple photos and this has to be uploaded to  http://uploads.im . Once I get a success response from the API with the url of the uploaded image, I need to upload another and so on. Also, Once I have all the images's uploaded to the image server I need to send the URL list to my server, which stores these details.

Here is what I have done till now

```
@OnClick({R.id.pic_photo_0
        , R.id.pic_photo_1
        , R.id.pic_photo_2
        , R.id.pic_photo_3
}) //Bind with butterknife
public void onClickPhotoFrame(View view)
{
    // Start CameraActivity
    Intent startCustomCameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(startCustomCameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
    {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        //based on which imageview created the camera request, load it with the above image
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photoUri).fit().into(imageView0);
    }
}
```

1) In the above code is it possible to know which view called the onActivityResult method? Based on that I can set the imageview with the thumbnail from camera.

2) I am also adding the uri returned by the camera to a arraylist, which can be used later to loop and upload the image. Please let me know if this approach is OK.

I am uploading the image as below via retrofit

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageStorageList.size(); i++)
{
    Call<ImageUploadResponse> call = new ImageUploadHelper().
            UploadImage(new File(imageStorageList.get(i).getPath()));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageUploadResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, Response<ImageUploadResponse> response)
        {
            // do some magic here to know which image was uploaded
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, Throwable t)
        {


        }
    });
}
```

3) I am very sure the above strategy is not OK. Please help me how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) In the above code is it possible to know which view called the
>   onActivityResult method? Based on that I can set the imageview with
>   the thumbnail from camera.

There is no standard way to know, which `View` started a camera `Intent`. If you really need to know it, you can create local variable:

```
private ImageView lastClickedView;
```

Then in `onClickPhotoFrame` do this:

```
public void onClickPhotoFrame(View view){
    lastClickedView = (ImageView) view;
    // Start CameraActivity
    Intent startCustomCameraIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(startCustomCameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

And in `onActivityResult` add handling for this case:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
    {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        //based on which imageview created the camera request, load it with the above image
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photoUri).fit().into(lastClickedView);
    }
}
```

> 2) I am also adding the uri returned by the camera to a arraylist,
>   which can be used later to loop and upload the image. Please let me
>   know if this approach is OK.

In my opinion, your approach is OK. But I've seen your another answer: [Call same retrofit method sequentially for result using RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824727/call-same-retrofit-method-sequentially-for-result-using-rxjava)

As I understood, you want to do it using RxJava.

So, this is one of possible methods(copied from your answer and changed a bit):

```
Observable.from(imageStorageList)
          .flatMap(uri -> new ImageUploadHelper().uploadImage(new File(uri.getPath())))
           .subscribe(imageUploadResponseObservable -> {

                }, throwable -> {/*handle it here*/});
```

## Advantages:

- Simple implementation

## Disadvantages:

- Actually this variant doesn't handle errors. I mean, in error case, you need to try to upload image again.

How to solve this problem?

**I.** Without RxJava, look at this like on jobs. And use library [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue). These jobs will be **persistent**, and in error case, they will be repeated with exponential back-off.

**II.** Implement your own mechanism, which will upload images on server and will be persistent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have another question. After I finish uploading the image, can I make another retrofit call from onCompleted() method using the data I received from this call. If not, how can I chain another retrofit call? All the examples I have seen shows that flatmap is used to chain call. In my case, I am not understanding how to perform this call

Comment: @rakeshkashyap, suppose `uploadImage` returns some `imageUploadResponse`. In this case you should do next:
`.flatMap(uri -> new ImageUploadHelper().uploadImage(new File(uri.getPath()))).map(response -> {/*do what you want with response*/})`

Comment: I am not able to get this concept yet. I have a gist here https://gist.github.com/rakesh1988/841f668f49c46ed6e5ce668003d12b17 In my case I need to wait till I upload all the images. List that I am building in onNext() has to be the input for my next API call. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @rakeshkashyap, sorry, I didn't get it. In this case you need this: `.flatMap(uri -> new ImageUploadHelper().uploadImage(new File(uri.getPath()))).toList().map(list -> {/*do something with list*/})`

Comment: @rakeshkashyap, but it will be another list, not `responseArrayList`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still not able to get the concept right. can you please have a look at my gist https://gist.github.com/rakesh1988/841f668f49c46ed6e5ce668003d12b17 .... I tried using toList(), as expected, I got List<ImageUploadResponse>. chaining .map(list -> {//not getting this magical code}). I am trying to set the list to "User" class and use "User" class to call second API. I have pasted my code in the gist

Comment: @rakeshkashyap, please, look at this: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderGarmash/8f4d34e86b75e00487c6028b2059a9c7

Comment: It would have taken me months, if I had tried to come up with a solution of this kind. Probably its because I have not understood RX completely. I am still in the process of learning. 
Thanks a tonne for your help. Finally I was able to pull the string. I have updated my code in my gist to handle failures in first call. If possible please do comment on the same. Once again, I am really grateful for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110540/discussion-between-alexander-and-rakesh-kashyap).